# Xcode showing analyzer result

Tags: iphone

When I run the XCode analyzer on my project, I get a warning message "value stored to flagReturn is never read".

```
int flagReturn=0;
NSString *alreadyChkin=[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:btnCheckin.titleLabel.text];      

    if (lastMchkin!=0 || lastFchkin!=0 &&[alreadyChkin isEqualToString:@"Check in"]) 
    {
        flagReturn=1;    ////here it is showing analyzer
        [mTabBarHost funChangeNavTitle:lastPlaceName];
        [self funDesignSecondView];     
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Make it more clear. It's diff to understand.

Comment: Sarah i am using flag with name "flagReturn" in if condition when i am trying to set "flagReturn=1" xcode is showing analyzer.pls help how can i remove this.

Comment: But its diff to trace. Even your if condition and the variable lastMchkin and others too.

Comment: It's basically saying that you're never using the value stored in `flagReturn`. If you want to get rid of the warning, simply delete the two instances of `flagReturn`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
return;
```

Do you mean

```
return flagReturn;
```

Currently, you set a value to the variable and then leave the method, so as it says you are never using the value you have stored.